# Why are only the default skins allowed in tournaments?

Tags: overwatch, competitive-gaming

Is there a specific in-game/competitive-gaming reason as to why only the default skins are allowed in tournaments? I never see teams using the alternate skins, only sprays, emotes, voice-lines, and gold weapons.

Comment: I don't know about the specific reasoning for Overwatch, but there's a similar rule for League of Legends tournaments. The reasoning there is because some skins make certain heroes hard to differentiate from one another, or their particle effects are hard to see. It's also easier for spectator to tell which character is which, especially if they don't actually play the game often themselves.

Comment: @MageXy I want to highlight the spectators here. Some people watch tournaments but don't play the game themself (yet). Having understandable and fun to watch tournaments can make people motivated to buy the game.

Comment: @MageXy in LoL only some skins are disallowed in tournaments, most skins are perfectly fine.

Comment: In league, only skins that make viewing hard or give a specific advantage through their visuals are banned.

Comment: There is a reason for such things. When Genji reflects a Dragon from Hanzo who has a skin th genji doesnt have, It causes the dragon to be invisible.

Comment: @Luciferangel source on that? I remember this bug, but I believe that's been fixed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's all about being able to easily identify characters, especially in large team fights. While most competitive players are probably able to identify characters no matter what skin they're using, it helps take away some distraction from the core game.

Comment: It also makes the characters easier to recognize for spectators that don't necessarily play the game.

Comment: Is there a rule list somewhere? As this answer goes, it seems more like opinion, despite my agreeing with you.

Comment: It also looks like all the players get new accounts for the tournament. Every vod I've watched of the OW tournaments have everyone at level 1- and therefore unable to have obtained a skin as custom games don't award exp.

Comment: @KizTrap Perhaps I'm seeing gold weapons for LANs.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I will admit I don't watch that many tournaments. And when I do I'm usually too busy being sad that there's not enough Pharah in play. :P

Comment: There are, in fact, hitbox differences between D.Va's skins. The Taegeukgi has a larger hitbox than most others, such that her ult can clip through walls if the mech is positioned close to one.